# How to set if condition for not printing message when the record is found?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php require("connections.php");//to make connection with database
    error_reporting(0); ?> <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post"
    action="searchtry.php"> <table width="700" border="0" align="center"
    cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">   <tr>
        <td colspan="9" align="center"> 
        <input type="text" name="rollno" />   <input name="search" type="submit" value="search" />   </td>   </tr>   <tr>    <td
    colspan="9" align="center"></td>   </tr>   <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>student name</td>
        <td>Roll no.</td>
        <td>Hindi</td>
        <td>English</td>
        <td>Maths</td>
        <td>Sanskrit</td>
        <td>Science</td>
        <td>Action</td>
           </tr>   <?php    if(isset($_POST["search"]) and $_POST["rollno"]!="")   {   $msg="no record found";  
    $rollno=$_POST["rollno"];   $sql="SELECT * FROM student WHERE rollno
    = $rollno";   $result=mysql_query($sql);   $found == false;   //$row=mysql_fetch_array($result)   ?>   <tr>   <?php 
            if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {   $found == true;     ?>
        <td><?php echo $row["sid"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["sname"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["rollno"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["hindi"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["english"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["maths"];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row["sanskrit"];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["science"];?></td>
        <td>
        <a href="delete.php?sid=<?php echo $row["sid"];?>">Delete</a>| 
        <a href="edit.php?sid=<?php echo $row["sid"];?>">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
         <?php      }
        if($found == false)     { echo "$msg";}}   ?>
          </table> </form> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single = is **assignment** operator; double == is for **comparison**. You are not assigning `true` to `$found` but comparing,

Change `$found == true;` to `$found = true;` same at time of initializing your variable.

```
$found = false;
```

Comment: thanks... .. .. changing this sorted out many many things correct but message is still not coming.. though all code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to check if there was a retrieve record on your query.. you can use..

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      // your code here
   }
}else{
   echo "no record found";
}
```

please avoid using mysql, rather use PDO;
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: if i set my code in this format it gives me following error 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in D:\xampp\htdocs\Study\student\searchtry.php on line 68

Comment: check your closing braces '{}'